# Foundation5 off canvas not clickable on phone

Tags: ios, canvas, zurb-foundation-5

I can't get the off canvas to show up on click on my iPhone. I used the same code from foundation but it still don't work.

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
<div class="inner-wrap">
<nav class="tab-bar">
<div class="left-small">
<a role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="idOfLeftMenu" class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"   ><span></span></a>
</div>
<section class="middle tab-bar-section">
<h1 class="title">lorem</h1> 
</section>
</nav>
<!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
<!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
<a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
```

Comment: The [post](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1651-cant-get-off-canvas-to-toggle-on-mobile) doesn't help you ?

Comment: You're missing closing DIVs.